# jQuery in Master / Content page in ASP.NET ignored

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, c#-4.0, master-pages

I'm trying to use jQuery on ASP.NET and actually the code below works perfectly!

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico"/>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>    
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <link href="Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#txtDateFrom").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy' })
        });
        $(function () {
            $("#txtDateTo").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy' })
        });        
    </script>
</head>
```

But if i use jQuery on Mater / Content page ASP.NET, the jQuery is ignored.

Master Page :

```
<head runat="server">
    <title>asdf</title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>    
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <link href="Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico"/>
    <link href="StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">

    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div runat="server" id="top_outer"></div>
        <div runat="server" id="outer">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Content Page :

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
    <script type="text/javascript">        
        $(function () {
            $("#txtDateFrom").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy' })
        });
        $(function () {
            $("#txtDateTo").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy' })
        });
    </script>
</asp:Content>
```

Does anyone have idea why?

**EDIT:**
I got the code below from "View Page Source" in Chrome and when I check each link of javascript, the page shows the javascript code. How can i check if jQuery is properly  loaded or not?

```
<head><title>
    asdf
</title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>    
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <link href="Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" /><link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" /><link href="StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript">        
        $(function () {
            $("#txtDateFrom").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy' })
        });
        $(function () {
            $("#txtDateTo").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy' })
        });
    </script>
</head>
```

Comment: From the code here its is not ignored - but you have made some other error, probably is not found on the directory you have give. Check if the jQuery is loaded and if the directories are correct placed relative to the page position.

Comment: Is the link to the jQuery script file correct for the page you are viewing? The relative path needs to be relative from the page not the master page. That's caught me a few times.

Comment: If you use a browser debugger such as Firebug, Chrome Tools etc do they give any further information?

Comment: How can i tell jQuery is properly loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to change **"#txtDateFrom"** to **"#<%=txtDateFrom.ClientID %>"** and now it works fine!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#<%=txtDateFrom.ClientID %>").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy' })
    });
    $(function () {
        $("#<%=txtDateTo.ClientID %>").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy' })
    });
</script>
```